# :not selector for all inputs they are not in a UL with class .input-list?

Tags: css, less

This is my Mixin:

```
.dialog-inputs() {
  :not(.input-list) {
    label,
    input,
    select,
    textarea {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

I Want that all inputs etc, got this 2 Styles when its no UL around there with class .input-list... But this Less Code dont work =/ Any Idea?

Comment: I assume you are calling the mixin somewhere because otherwise no CSS would get output. Please show us your HTML also so that we can validate the correctness of the selector.

Comment: Here a Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/99utpu

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? The way you have written it now means all of the labels, inputs etc in the list will get the styles (because not all the containers they're in have the class `input-list`). Is that the problem?

Comment: I want that this 2 styles dont work on inputs and labels when they are in a ul with class input-list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the sub-selectors of a selector are applied to all elements that they can be applied to.

Simplified, if you have this

```css
.block :not(.list) input {background:red}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <input/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In the above example, the input is red because the `div` matches `.block` and the `li` matches `:not(.list)`!

So the solution in this simplified example is to just make the `:not(.list)` more specific by adding `ul` in front of it.

```css
.block ul:not(.list) input {background:red}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <input/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, that won't always do the trick. In your code, you have nested `ul`s, which will complicate matters.

Therefore, a more thorough solution is to write out in full what your intention is: "make all inputs red, except the ones in `.list` lists, which should have the default color".

```css
.block input {background:red}

.block .list input {background:initial}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <input/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is a bit longer, but it will work, no matter what!

By the way, sorry I can't use your exact source. Stack snippets don't support LESS (or, I don't know how to make LESS work in a snippet). But I hope you get the point and you can adapt this to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was only that i forgot the & Symbol in before the ul =)

```
.dialog-inputs() {
 "&"ul:not(.input-list) {
    label,
    input,
    select,
    textarea {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```